# WARNING - dangerous use of the global this object?

Tags: javascript, oop, google-closure-compiler

Google closure compiler complains about this code:

```
function Message() {
    this.message = "";
    this.nickname = "";
    this.time = 0;
    this.my = false;
};
```

What is dangerous here? How else it is supposed to create "objects"? For now I do

```
var m = new Message();
```

to get an initialized object of "type" Message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try annotating the code to tell the compiler that this is a constructor function:

```
/**
 * A message
 * @constructor
 */
function Message() {
    this.message = "";
    this.nickname = "";
    this.time = 0;
    this.my = false;
};
```

See https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#overview

Comment: Yes, this is an option, but I am interested in roots of the problem. What crime the google closure compiler has detected there?

Comment: the compiler thinks you are referring to the window object, not the instance of Message, because it doesn't know if Message is a constructor or not

Comment: one of the basic features of compilers is type checking, that's why you need to annotate.

Comment: @pavelkolodin in ES5, there is no way to determine whether a function is a constructor or not until it's used so you have to add a constructor annotation. ES6 classes take care of this. The error comes from `var m = Message() //no new`